# How to pass a function to link component in react router v6

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-context

There is a function that I want to pass to a link component. How would I do it? I tried using state and useLocation and while they work good for normal variables, useLocation sends null when trying to pass down a function.

```
const function=someFunction(){}

<Link state={func:function} to="/LoginScreen" style={style.a} >
  Login
</Link>
```

This does not work.

Code trying to use a React context:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

const RefreshDisplayContext = React.createContext();

function Launchpad() {
  const [launchpadState, updatelaunchpadState] = useState({
    userIsLoggedIn: false
  });

  function refreshDisplay(event) {
    updatelaunchpadState({ userIsLoggedIn: true });
  }

  return (
    <RefreshDisplayContext.Provider value={refreshDisplay}>
      <div>
        {launchpadState.userIsLoggedIn ? (
          <p>User is Logged In </p>
        ) : (
          <p>User is Not Logged In </p>
        )}

        <Link to="login" state={launchpadState}>
          Login via Child
        </Link>
      </div>
    </RefreshDisplayContext.Provider>
  );
}

export { Launchpad, RefreshDisplayContext };
```

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { RefreshDisplayContext } from "../routes/Launchpad";

function Login(props) {
  const refreshDisplay = React.useContext(RefreshDisplayContext);

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => refreshDisplay({ userIsLoggedIn: true })}
    >
      Login
    </button>
  );
}

export { Login };
```

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import { Launchpad } from "./routes/Launchpad";
import { Login } from "./routes/Login";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Launchpad />} />
      <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
    </Routes>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

[Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mjoycemilburn/contextprobdemo)

Comment: You can only send JSON serializable data in route state. Functions won't work. Why are you trying to send a function via route state? What are you trying to accomplish overall? You may just need to store the function globally and pass an identifier to the receiving component to use to access the function you want to call there.

Comment: In the project I created Components display diffrent things based on the state of user. Said components can change the state of user, so what I am trying to do here is defining a user state and send its setter to the components so that they can change it while re rendering correctly. All the components use and modify the same state. I thought about defining a state in app.js and passing  down the setter function using routes but it did not seem right.

Comment: Using a React context might be useful here then.

Comment: @Utonyum If you want multiple components to access the same state. The efficient way is, You should go either with context api or redux which handles the centralized state management system.

Comment: I think a React context should work in this situation. Can you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo of your code that we could inspect live?

Comment: @Drew Reese. React context doesn't seem to work here either - React.useContext on my imported context returns 'undefined'. I can see why the JSON route doesn't work, but this additional problem really leaves me stumped! What I'm trying to do is trigger a state change at the calling end of my <Link>.

Comment: @Drew Reese Thanks for your quick response. Would you like to try this [sandbox_link](https://codesandbox.io/s/github/mjoycemilburn/contextprobdemo)? Repo is at [contex_prob_repo](https://github.com/mjoycemilburn/contextprobdemo). Clicking the login button should use the context's callback fn and display "User logged In".

Answer (score 1):

## Issue

The issue with the code is that you are only rendering the `RefreshDisplayContext` around the UI/ReactTree that the `Launchpad` component is rendering. When the link to `"/login"` is clicked and the app navigates to that route and renders `Login`, the component being rendered is *outside* the
React context it's trying to access, and since there's also no default value, `refreshDisplay` can't be accessed from the undefined context value.

## Solution

Move the `RefreshDisplayContext.Provider` higher in the ReactTree so that it is able to provide the same context value to all consumers.

Create a new file to declare and export the context.

refreshDisplay.context.js

```
import { createContext, useContext, useState } from "react";

export const RefreshDisplayContext = createContext({
  refreshDisplay: () => {}
});

export const useRefreshDisplay = () => useContext(RefreshDisplayContext);

const RefreshDisplayProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [launchpadState, updatelaunchpadState] = useState({
    userIsLoggedIn: false
  });

  function refreshDisplay(event) {
    updatelaunchpadState({ userIsLoggedIn: true });
  }

  return (
    <RefreshDisplayContext.Provider value={{ launchpadState, refreshDisplay }}>
      {children}
    </RefreshDisplayContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default RefreshDisplayProvider;
```

Import and wrap all the components you want to have access to the `RefreshDisplayContext`.

index.js

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import RefreshDisplayProvider from "./refreshDisplay.context";
import { Launchpad } from "./routes/Launchpad";
import { Login } from "./routes/Login";

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));

root.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <RefreshDisplayProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Launchpad />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
      </Routes>
    </RefreshDisplayProvider>
  </BrowserRouter>
);
```

Update the consumers to access the provided context value.

Launchpad

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { useRefreshDisplay } from "../refreshDisplay.context";

export function Launchpad() {
  const { launchpadState } = useRefreshDisplay();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        User is {launchpadState.userIsLoggedIn ? "Logged In" : "Not Logged In"}
      </p>

      <Link to="login" state={launchpadState}>
        Login via Child
      </Link>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Login

```
import React from "react";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useRefreshDisplay } from "../refreshDisplay.context";

function Login(props) {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { refreshDisplay } = useRefreshDisplay();

  return (
    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() => {
        refreshDisplay();
        navigate("/", { replace: true });
      }}
    >
      Login
    </button>
  );
}

export { Login };
```

[image: Edit how-to-pass-a-function-to-link-component-in-react-router-v6]

Comment: Many thanks Drew. I can confirm this works. But it's complicated and some heavy consequences follow for my particular webapp. This has a good deal more structure than the sandbox. I may be back!

Comment: @MartinJ Great, glad it works for you in the interim. I don't find it to be very complicated, but the idea is more to help you see and understand how to organize and structure your code to pass data *down* the ReactTree. What are the "some heavy consequences" you refer to? A React context is great for simple global app state, but if you've *much* more complicated app state then you might consider an *actual* state management tool like Redux.

Comment: Just to confirm - my webapp now works. The "heavy consequences" stemmed from my misunderstanding of your code. I was trying to add launchpad state to the context and hadn't appreciated that this was already there! refreshDisplay.context uses syntax that I'm not familiar with. Thanks again for your work.